# Foreignkey translate to charfield

Tags: django, message

I 'm trying user to user message app.But sender and recipient is combobox ı dont want combobox.I want to charfield (input) sender and recipient. How to do this

```
class mesaj(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='gonderen',blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='alici',on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    message = models.TextField()
    sent = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: You need to make a [form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/) with connected [views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/views/) if you want to change the interactable interface for the models.

Comment: I assume you're using a `ModelForm` currently?

Comment: please show views(I am newbie, coding)

Comment: I use ModelForm and I trying for days but I cant